# What does a light blue Lync presence indicate?

Tags: microsoft-office, lync-2013

When viewing a user's Lync presence in Office applications, we sometimes see a light blue icon instead of the normal colors. Since I know that white is what happens when the presence isn't available, I'm somewhat confused as to what light blue means. It doesn't appear as an option under my own Availability settings in Lync, and I haven't been able to find its meaning after a few searches. I was able to find another screenshot showing the same light blue indicator, however:

[image]

It doesn't seem to be an indication of time away, as I've seen it show up for some users after as little as 45 minutes while someone else may still show yellow after a few days.

**What does this light blue color indicate as regards to a user's availability in Lync?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What does this light blue color indicate as regards to a user's availability in Lync?

[image] means Offline:

> **Description**
>
> You’re not signed in. You’ll appear as Offline to people whom you’ve blocked from seeing your presence.
>
> **How this status gets set**
>
> Lync sets this status when you log off your computer.

Source [Understand presence](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-presence-ccd83078-36bb-454b-a273-73fc6b6910f2)